# Second "s" in names that ends with the s

Tags: punctuation, possessives

Well, it's one particular name from One-Punch Man, Genos. 
Sometimes i see it's written as Geno'**s** arm/body parts or something along the line, but not the Geno**s**'**s** arm/body parts.
Where did second s go?

Comment: Do you mean `Genos'`? `Geno's` as a possessive of `Genos`  is clearly an error.

Comment: So there should be two S? Like Genos's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character's name is [**Genos**.](http://onepunchman.wikia.com/wiki/Genos)

The possessive of Genos can be `Genos'` or `Genos's`, [which is a matter of style.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/108153/154521) However, `Geno's` is an error, as it would require that his actual name be Geno - which it is not.